# Informix Connection is success but not able to select the Informix table in OLE DB Source editer in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, informix

I have successfully connected Informix connection in my SSIS connection manager so there should be no problem in Informix Service Provider Configuration in my 32-bit Windows machine. After creating connection, I opened OLE DB Source with Informix Service Provider, and in Data access mode, I selected SQL Command and used "select * from informix table". But when I click Cloumns view or Ok button its throughing error

```
TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.



------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202009 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

[image]

[image]

I'm sure this table is existing in the connected Informix DB. I tried to fix this issue but failed. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Couple of questions
In the connection manger dialog window when you click on 'Test Connection' does it connect successfully?
Are you able to confirm the table does exist in the database you are connecting to

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that even if you're connecting through OLEDB it's going to access informix through ODBC protocol.  Ensure that you have the right drivers for 32 bit informix thru IBM (link below).  If you're still having issues after installing those drivers and rebooting it would be best to set up an ODBC connection on your box (and the server running it once deployed).  It'll be saving you one layer of data access anyway.

http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/search.jsp?q=&pf=&S_TACT=&S_CMP=&status=Active&sr=1&cat=&q0=&k=ALL&b=&pn=&pid=&rs=ifxdl&fpf=Windows+2000&fdt=&flang=&sb=ra&ibm-go.x=10&ibm-go.y=15